# Finding cycles in a directed graph implemented using an unordered multimap

Tags: c++, c++11, directed-graph

So, I've implemented a directed graph using an unordered multimap. Each pair within the map is made up of two strings: the vertex and its adjacent vertex.
Now, I am trying to determine if my graph has a cycle, and if so, how big is the cycle. This is the code I have so far:

```
int findCycle(const unordered_multimap<string,string> & connectedURLVertices, string y, string key)
{
        string position;

        position=y.find(key);

        if(position!=string::npos)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        auto nodesToCheck=connectedURLVertices.equal_range(key);

        for(auto & node : nodesToCheck)
        {
            int z=findCycle(connectedURLVertices,y+key,node);
        }
}
```

I've walked through the code on paper and it seems to be logically correct, but I would appreciate it if anyone could take a look and see if I am on the right track or missing anything. Thanks!

Comment: Most likely you want to pass that `unordered_multimap` by const reference.

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't return anything if you never enter the branch `if(position!=string::npos)`. Most likely leading to undefined behavior. Why don't you use [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm)?

Comment: Write some tests and see yourself. As an improvement, I'd suggest giving `y` and `key` some documentation and perhaps a new name. Also, think about possible restrictions on their values imposed by the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

To search for cycles in a graph you have to descend recursively through the arcs from some initial node until you reach one already visited node (you can construct a `std::set` of already visited nodes or mark the nodes as you visit them) or exhaust all the nodes without getting one already visited (absence of cycles)  The criterion to select the arc can be adjusted to find it more quickly or the kind of search (first in depth, search by level, etc.)